# How to inspect elements and click on Apple Script

Tags: applescript

I'm pretty new with apple scripts, and I'm trying to change the focus mode in the system preferences via Apple Script (the shortcut way is not an option). And I found one script that enables the Don't Disturb mode. But it doesn't change the mode.
How can I inspect the window and click select the focus mode?

Here is the script:

```
        tell application "System Preferences"
            set current pane to pane "com.apple.preference.notifications"
        end tell
        
        delay 0.5
        
        tell application "System Events"
            tell application process "System Preferences"
                click radio button "Focus" of tab group 1 of window "Notifications & Focus"
        
                click checkbox 1 of group 1 of tab group 1 of window "Notifications & Focus"
        
                set theCheckbox to checkbox 1 of group 1 of tab group 1 of window "Notifications & Focus"
                tell theCheckbox
                    set theCheckboxStatus to value of theCheckbox as boolean
                    if theCheckboxStatus is true then
                        display notification "Do not disturb is on"
                    else
                        delay 0.2
                        display notification "Do not disturb is off"
                    end if
                end tell
        
            end tell
        end tell
```

And this is the window:

[image]